# New tab in gnome-terminal closes on pressing Ctrl+C

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, dotnet

I'm writing a bash script that runs few microservices at once.

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t 'test' -- sh -c "cd Services/Api; dotnet run --no-build; bash";
```

The command works fine but when I press Ctrl+C to stop the application the tab closes itself. I would like the tab to stay opened in the specified directory.

See the screenshot:

[image: RESULT]

Answer (score 0):

I used following thread to solve this issue 
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242826/how-to-stop-pressing-ctrlc-from-closing-the-gnome-terminal)

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t 'test' -- bash -ic "endyarnstart() { exec bash; };trap endyarnstart INT;cd Services/Api;dotnet run --no-build;exec bash";
```