# How to stop pressing ctrl+c from closing the gnome terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome

```
gnome-terminal --tab --title="watch reason" --command="bash -c 'yarn start'"
```

Running this command would open up a new terminal an run the script start.

But on pressing control+c the terminal closes.

How can this be prevented so that pressing control+c would stop the script but the terminal does not close.

Comment: Create a terminal, then type in and run the command from within that terminal.

Comment: @DougSmythies I have to run three npm scripts. So instead of manually doing that every time I thought a script would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and the solution is to **trap the Ctrl+C**.

When Ctrl+C is pressed, you want the terminal to return to bash as if you had typed in the command manually.  You can trap the Ctrl+C signal (INT) and run `exec bash` instead.

This would look like:

`gnome-terminal --tab --title="watch reason" --command="bash -c 'endyarnstart() { exec bash; }; trap endyarnstart INT; yarn start;'"`

This will call the function endyarnstart when you press Ctrl+C, which will start bash and the terminal will behave as normal from then on.